# Cómo puedo desplegar un Javascript hecho con Node JS para hacer envios de correos, que pueda vincularse con un Frontend hecho en Angular en otro Host

Tags: nodejs, iis

Tengo por primera vez en mi trabajo la situación de que Desplegué mi Frontend de Angular en un hosting de PLESK, y me dijeron que despliegue mi backend, que en realidad es un javascript hecho a través de Nodemailer, y es la primera vez que me tocó usar estas librerias de Node por lo que soy novato en esto...

lo desplegué utilizando el comando pkg, generando un ejecutable y lo pegué al archivo en un IIS 2019...

el problema surge que mi IIS no maneja protocolos HTTPS, el cual maneja el hosting de PLESK en donde tengo desplegado mi frontend de Angular...

y cuando llamo al Ejecutable del Node en el ISS a través de un botón no hace el envío de mail que debería y por consola me sale este error que subo en el screen :

[image: screen]

El error dice: Blocked loaded  mixed active content  y por lo que estuve investigando se da cuando se envían peticiones desde un host con Protocolo HTTPS a uno con HTTP